# From an app, is it possible the get the real IP address if the client installed a VPN?

Tags: android, ios, ip, vpn, android-vpn-service

From an app, is it possible the get the real IP address if the client installed a VPN ? this for Android and/or ios.

Comment: What is the "real IP address"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, your public IP would be the one from the VPN and your local IP is only good in your Local Network

Comment: thanks javier, but most of the time the local IP is my internet provider IP no? I mean i need to use my internet connection to get access to the vpn so in my mobile I have for sure a connection with the IP that my internet provider gave me

Comment: Much of the time your local IP won't be your Internet provider IP as many networks use Network Address Translation (NAT).  If you see an address starting with 10 or 192.168 then NAT is in operation for sure.  If the network uses IPv6 then the local address may well be a provider address.